# Why my OpenGL context is null in this function and not in the other

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using GUI framework which provides OpenGL implementation using a special widget.

This widget create one OpenGL context as initialization and provide several overridable function (GLPaint(), GLResize() ...)

This OpenGL widget is inherited from a super base class called Ctrl which provide some key/Mouse handling via overriding function ( Key(...) to handle Keyboard  MouseMove(...) to handle the mouse move etc...)

If I try to run OpenGL functions such as glCreateBuffers in GLPaint() or GLResize() it will work perfectly. However when trying to run OpenGL function in all of overriden super base class it wont work anymore.

I have checked the Thread PID between execution on GLPaint() and Key() and they both the same so I don't get why I lose my context in this functions. I had try to retrieve it using wglMakeCurrent(...) with the base args widget use in the Context creation function but it don't work either.

**Here come my question: Is context attach to a thread of to an Object? Is there some way to lose the context in a thread by error? Do you have idea of what I'm experiencing?**

**If you have any information about the OpenGL context lifetime I would be really grateful if you would share it** (it is really hard to find information about it without facing the classic multithreading context cohabitation problem)

Comment: Probably because someone called `wglMakeCurrent(NULL)`?

Comment: Ok you are right, a wglMakeCurrent(Null) was in hidded in internal function fo the widget